# How would I split currency at difference exchange rates?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Say Bob buys £100 worth of dollars, and gets $135 for his investment (1.35 Exchange rate).

Then Dave buys £75 worth of dollars, a week later, and gets $95 for his investment (1.26 Exchange rate).

Bob and Dave decide to store all the dollars in the same account, for sake of ease. The exchange rate back to pounds suddenly soars to 5.50 and now their combined dollars are worth 5.50 * (135) + (95) = £1265

How do Bob and Dave split their $1265, taking into account the different initial amounts of dollars purchased AND the different exchange rates? Or are there too many variables involved to calculate this?

Comment: The answer to this nonmathematical question is that they must agree on what's fair - something between the pounds they spent and the dollars they put in.

Comment: Imagine if this were not exchanges but selling something else.  Imagine Bob provided 135 flowerpots and Dave provided 95 flower pots and they sold them for 5.50 each.  Then the split it 135-95.  Would it make sense for Dave to say he is entitled to more because he spent £75 on his 95 pots but Bob only spent £100 on his 135 pots?  Why should that make any difference?  Or did they decide hey, you buy £75 and I'll buy £100 worth of pots and we'll sell 'em and split them 75-100?  Depends on what they agreed to ahead of time.

Comment: How does this question have anything to do with linear algebra?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I see it is together they had $\$135 + \$95 = \$230$ total of which Bob provided $\frac {135}{230}={27}{46}$ of it and Dave provided $\frac {95}{230}=\frac {19}{46}$ of it.

So Bob is entitled to $£ 1265*\frac{27}{46}=£742.5$ of it and Dave is entitled to $£ 1265*\frac{19}{46}=£522.5$ of it.

Of course, they could have came up with another agreement.  They could have said "It doesn't matter how many dollars we each provided; we each provided Pounds (which is *real* money not that kooky foreign stuff...) so Bob is entitled to $\frac {100}{100+75} = \frac 47$ and Dave is entitled to $\frac {75}{100+75} = \frac 37$ of it."

I don't see why they *should* as they each invested on their *own* but either way could be argued.

(Or they could just agree to split everything 50-50.  Or Dave could hit Bob on the head and take all the money... they can ultimately do whatever they want.)

Answer (score 1):

Did they agree to invest their pounds in dollars or did they agree to pool dollars, hoping the exchange rate would go up?  In the second case it should not matter where the dollars came from, they divide the account according to the dollars contributed.  The first case is much more nebulous.  It would have been cleaner for them to contribute pounds to an account and change the account into dollars.  Even if they did multiple times at different rates, it is not one person's pounds that are changed and it is clear they are sharing the exchange rate risk.  The situation is not well enough defined to have a clear answer.  It is also not math.